# SSH / SCP Server on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, storage-area-network, scp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)

Can anyone on the SF community recommend a trustworthy/easy to set up SCP server for windows.  I do not want to go through the trouble of setting up Cygwin but I have a need for running SCP on Windows.

As a summary, our networks are very highly firewalled, and SSH ports are allowed only through a jump server which uses two-factor authentication using an RSA key on the Linux/Unix side, and FTP is blocked by default.

Without requesting firewall rules for dozens of SAN switches to do firmware upgrades, I would like to have an SCP server running on my primary DCFM server, which is Windows based, to allow me to perform SAN switch firmware upgrades using my central repository, but without having to request FTP access all over the place.

Any ideas?

Comment: See also [Is IIS SFTP natively supported by Windows Server 2012 R2?](http://serverfault.com/q/648855/168875)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18292/what-are-some-good-ssh-servers-for-windows

[What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

Vshell by [Vandyke Software](http://www.vandyke.com) is the only decent ssh / sftp server I've found for the Windows platform.

Comment: I have heard good things about vandyke, however, bitvise is not too bad and much cheaper

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.itefix.no/i2/copssh

while there please check out their hardbackup. It's a port of Dirvish to windows and a thing of beauty.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried doing this however the openSSH webpage links to [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), maybe this could be used.

Comment: er... WinSCP is a client, not a server, right?

Answer (score -2):

Use [bitvise](https://www.bitvise.com/ssh-server) to install on Windows box
then use a ssh or scp client to connect to it ! 
I'm making an assumption you are familiar with ssh private/public key setup etc. If you are thinking about automation for downloading or copying.

Comment: ...perhaps because of the restrictions stated in the question (not wanting to have to alter firewall rules for dozens of hosts)?