# Recommend an SFTP solution for Windows (Server & Client) that integrates well with Dreamweaver

Tags: windows, security, ftp, sftp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SSH / SCP Server on Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/10468/ssh-scp-server-on-windows)

Could you please recommend a secure FTP solution for updating files on a remote windows server  from windows workstations?

We would like to replace the FTP-based workflow with a secure FTP one.

Windows Server 2003 on the remotely hosted webserver, WinXP on the workstations. We manage the files via Dreamweaver's built-in FTP. My understanding is Dreamweaver supports sFTP out of the box so I guess I am looking for a good sFTP server for Windows Server 2003. Ideally, that would not require cygwin.

Ideally, the solution would use authentication based on the existing windows accounts and permissions.

Thank you!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/8411/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/10468/

Answer (score 1):

I have used [SSH Tectia](http://www.ssh.com) with great success but it does cost.

Answer (score 0):

Consider upgrading to Windows Server 2008.  Microsoft provides a free sftp server that [works great.](http://blogs.technet.com/chrisavis/archive/2008/06/12/how-to-configure-ftp-over-ssl-secure-ftp-on-windows-2008-in-less-than-10-minutes.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. Given that our site runs ektron, I can't imagine going through a server os upgrade.

Comment: SFTP is not the same as FTP over TLS/SSL (what IIS does).

Answer (score 0):

It isn't free but [Cerberus FTP Server 4](http://www.cerberusftp.com/download.html) supports SFTP and works fine with Dreamweaver CS4.  Make sure you get version 4.0 or higher for SFTP support.

You also asked for an SFTP client solution.  Try Filezilla out. They have a good little SFTP client and it's completely free.

Please note, Windows 2008 and IIS support FTPS, not SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

CrushFTP has worked very well for us and is low cost.  Lots of options and integrated with AD.  HVery stable and great support for regular updates. Have not tested newest version as yet.

[CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com/)

Answer (score 0):

[CompleteFTP](http://enterprisedt.com/products/completeftp/) is an SFTP and FTP/FTPS server for Windows you might like to consider. It also supports HTTP and HTTPS. Disclosure: I am one of the developers of CompleteFTP.