# Port forwarding for Windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

How to "easily" forward incoming port `80`to outgoing to port: `8080` for Windows Server 2003? 
The idea is that all traffice/incoming and outgoing from/to port 80 will be redirected to 8080.

Comment: do you need a long term thing, or a one time fix?

Comment: Well a fix that will not persist upon reboot is still ok provided that it can be run through a batch file

Comment: What exactly are you trying to redirect? Just HTTP? Then you could just add port 80 to the HTTP server which currently listens on port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

install an ssh server, then use a local ssh client in a window, like:

```
 ssh username@localhost -R80:localhost:8080
```

ssh server: [What is a good SSH server to use on Windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows)

I'm not sure if this will work for port 80, but you could try it :)