# Change file and folder permissions without remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5, file-permissions

Currently, if I want to change permissions, I have to log in via remote desktop and do it from Windows Explorer, but I'm searching for simpler ways. (for example, a web based file manager)

Do you know any methods (web based file managers, etc.) to allow me changing permissions of files and folders without having to use remote desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd install an [SSH server](https://serverfault.com/q/8411/7200) and just use command-line tools like `icacls`. I think that's opening you up to less vulnerability than installing some webapp that will need to run in a permissions-elevated context.

Comment: Which SSH server do you suggest?

Comment: I use OpenSSH w/ Cygwin, personally: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/

Answer (score 2):

If both computers are on the same network you can open a UNC path to the administrative share of the drive where these files and folders exists and access the Security tab just as if you were logged on via RDP or via the console.

Comment: I assumed the OP was working with a machine that was in a hosting environment and not accessible w/ Windows File and Print Sharing. If it is accessible, though, this is clearly the best method.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand joeqwerty answer and @EvanAnderson comment... In my case, server is not in my local network, it's a remote VPS. So, Does this answer applicable to me or not?

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi - The odds are that the VPS host is filtering out the protocol necessary for this answer to work.

Comment: @MahdiGhiasi - No, this answer isn't relevant to your scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SetACL Studio](http://helgeklein.com/setacl-studio/). It works remotely just as well as locally and lets you manage permissions on files, directories, network shares, registry keys, printers, services, WMI objects. And it has undo...

[I am the author]

Comment: What's the protocol between the remote server and the client? The OP made it sound like they're in a scenario where they don't have unfiltered access to the remote machine (and probably can't get RPC through to it).

Comment: SetACL Studio uses the Windows APIs for accessing remote systems. So, yes, it is RPC.